# Apache Rewrite: How to write a rule based on domain name (instead of HTTP_HOST)?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I have written a RewriteRule which works on the basis of HTTP_HOST (www.domainname.com), but I want it to work on the basis of the domain name part only (domainname.com).

**To clarify further**

The folder structure is `/var/www/domainName.com`.

When I write this rule in apache conf file

```
RewriteRule ^/js/(.*) /%{HTTP_HOST}/js/$1 [L]
```

and access the site using www.mydomain.com -- it tries to find the folder `/var/www/www.domainName.com`, which does not exist.

So, I need to convert the above-mentioned rule to remove the "www" from the HTTP_HOST.

Comment: I gave an answer based on your rewrite-rule, but I am not sure if rewriting is the right way to go (see pulegium's answer about symlinks). Maybe you could clarify on what you want to achieve? There might be a simpler solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest that you redirect requests rather than make the same site available in two places.  Either create a new VirtualHost to redirect traffic:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.domainName.com
    Redirect / http://domainName.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Or add a set of rules above your others that will detect the presence of the www. prefix and redirect the user:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule /(.*) http://%1/$1 [R,L]
```

If you really want your site on both domain names without any redirection, you can use a RewriteCond to pull out just the domain name, and it will be available to the RewriteRule as %1.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/js/(.*) /%1/js/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

I doubt if you can do that, wouldn't it be easier just to create links to appropriate directories?

```
ln -s yourdomain.com www.yourdomain.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}`?

Also possible, if you have set `Servername` in your vhost to the same name you use in your directory structure, eg:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/domainame.com
  ServerName domainame.com
  ServerAlias www.domainame.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Then you can use `%{SERVER_NAME}` in your rewrite-rule.

Answer (score 0):

as i understand you question, just set your [DocumentRoot](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#documentroot) to the right directory:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/domainName.com
```